# jQuery: How can I capture event from one element and assign it to a different element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<a class="link" href="#">Link</a>

<button class="btn">
    BUTTON
</button>

<p class="hidden">This is a paragraph</p>
```

and the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link').on('click', function(){
        displayText();
    }); 

    function displayText(){
        $('p').show();
    }
});
```

The link when clicked displays the `<p>` tag. I want to capture the link event and assign it to the button. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
What I am looking for is to capture the event on a link and stop it, show a dialog box and assign the event to a button on the dialog box.

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ct4r7y0/**

Comment: Use `$('.btn')` instead of `$('.link')`. Or if you want both, `$('.btn, .link')`.

Comment: What should the button do? I mean... why not do it like `$(".btn").trigger("click")`? It's not clear what you're after... seems like an *XY problem* question

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Assigning an event to a DOM element is a pretty weird thing to do.

Comment: The function needs seems easy, but the question is hard.

Comment: Suggest you read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I am using a bootstrap modal box.

Comment: Well, you are *trying* to use a bootstrap modal box but I think you are bound to fail with that approach.

Comment: You are correct. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can **trigger** *click* on `button` with the event from `a.link` whenever link is clicked like this

```
$('.link').on('click', function(event){
    displayText();
    console.log(event);
    $('button').trigger('click', event);
});

// to test that the event is passing properly
$('button').on('click', function(event, originalEvent){
    console.log(event, originalEvent);

    //originalEvent.target === <a class="link"></a>
    //event.target === <button></button>
});
```

Note that the originalEvent there in button click handler is the event that was passed from `a.link`'s click.

Comment: Thank you but would it be possible to store the event and use it later? What I am looking for is to capture the event, show a dialog box and assign the event to a button on the dialog box.

Comment: yes why not, you can also make the button callback to store the originalevent using [curry pattern](http://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/)

Comment: Not sure how this would apply to my problem.

Comment: @ultimatecoder, questions questions ... a Javascript or jQuery event object has various properties. So which property(s) of the event do plan on using when it is used later? What will the stored event give you that is not available from the event generated by the button when it is clicked?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I am looking for continuity. I show a dialog box when there are form changes and the user tries to navigate away. On clicking "OK" on the dialog box, I want to close it and take the user to the page he earlier tried to click on. So, I'm thinking the click event needs to be stored and assigned to the "OK" button on the dialog. Unless there is a better way of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

May be you just can rebind that event(function) as another dom while you find the listeners on the dom which you want to capture, and hope  [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) can help you